# "Method not allowed" when using post request to create item

Tags: sitecore-services-client

[image]I modified to allow anonymous setting to true in Sitecore.Services.Client.config

```
var xhrp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhrp.open("POST", "http://sitecorenew.sc/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore%2Fcontent%2Fhome ");
        xhrp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhrp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                alert('Status: ' + this.status + '\nHeaders: ' + JSON.stringify(this.getAllResponseHeaders()) + '\nBody: ' + this.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhrp.send("{ \n    \"ItemName\": \"Home\", \n    \"TemplateID\": \"76036f5e-cbce-46d1-af0a-4143f9b557aa\", \n    \"Title\": \"Sitecore\", \n    \"Text\": \"\\r\\n\\t\\t\u003Cp\u003EWelcome to Sitecore\u003C/p\u003E\\r\\n\" \n}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate a authentication cookie and send that along with the request.  **FYI ... This must be called via HTTPS**

Get the cookie like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://sitecorenew.sc/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    alert('Status: '+this.status+'\nHeaders: '+JSON.stringify(this.getAllResponseHeaders())+'\nBody: '+this.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.send("{ \n \"domain\": \"sitecore\", \n \"username\": \"admin\", \n \"password\": \"b\" \n}");
```

Taken from:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/90/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice

Comment: i try this put still showing the same response 405 method not allowed

Comment: It seems that maybe you have might have IIS mis-configured.  Make sure you have your SSL setup correctly.

Comment: login response with ok 200 but create new response with 403 forbidden

Comment: Can you update your code to show what you've changed. After you get the cookie, you must pass it into your Create Item request. Your previous example doesn't show that.